# Replacing Attribute Values With New Values Based on the Old Values Using ArcMap Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I am using the Field Calculator of ArcMap.

I need to replace multiple values (codes) with another words in a field at one time in one script.

For example in my CodeField I need to replace "A01", "A02"... with "TextValue1", "TextValue2"...

How can I do this?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the GIS software in use.

Comment: Tags are all well and good, but the question *body* needs to contain the actual release of software in use. Coding questions here require a good-faith code attempt to solve the task.

Comment: Are you using the Python Parser or VBscript?  What does your code block look like so far?

Comment: In the field calculator, create a Code Block that defines a dictionary variable where the dictionary keys are the codes, and the dictionary values are the replacement text.  Then in the Expression, you do a simple dictionary lookup to replace the values (and you can even use an in-line `if` to check if the key exists first).

Comment: @SonofaBeach That´s what I looking for.

Comment: Good to hear.  I'd be happy to post a more comprehensive answer if the question gets re-opened.  But hopefully you've got it all working now anyhow.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should select the values in Attribute Table and by using Field Calculator you can add the right value.

Or, you can Start Editing and in TableOption of attribute table - you can use Replace function.

Comment: It's not completely clear what the OP wants, but this answer doesn't answer the question as completely as it could/should.

Comment: This answer is completely what he wants. ;)

You can try it before comments. I have used both ways several times.

Comment: Hi @EsHo, I get it. I'm looking for something more automated. I need to mark all the tags where the code starts with, for example, the letter and integer "A01" and rename the whole group with the text.

Comment: I've done the equivalent thousands of times, in six or more different ways with multiple software packages. But if you review the top-voted answers here, you'll see they contain much more complete answers with details on the exact procedure, including links to documentation and screen-shots. Since its not even clear what software is being used, and if the OP really wants a "script" as specified, it's still too early to answer correctly.